# MS Access write conflict when updating linked view

Tags: ms-access, azure-sql-database, odbc

I have a form (subform but that's irrelevant) which has a multi-table linked table view as its record source. We've never had any real issues when updating any columns via a form until now. We've migrated on premises SQL database to Azure SQL which means we've also had to start using ODBC Driver 17 for SQL server. Now when we try to update any field we get the infamouse Write Conflict error. I've had this many times and have been able to resolve by ensuring that all bit fields have default values and that none of the contain null values. On this occasion, I've also added timestamp fields to the relevant tables.

Despite this, I keep getting the write conflict error. I have another form with a single table view as its record source and I'm able to update that without any issues.

I have no underlying code that might be impacting this. I just try to change a single value and try to commit it using the write symbol. I've read a number of threads which suggest using a query instead of direct view/table bind, but this has worked for many years until now, and the query seems too difficult to construct as it contains a number joins which the MS Access doesn't seem to be able to cope with.

Any suggestions for what might be causing this issue or any work arounds?

View:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vewCardsLatestByPerson]
    AS
    SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.tblCard.crdID, 
    dbo.tblCard.crdStatus, dbo.tblCard.crdDate, 
    dbo.tblCard.crdExpiry, dbo.tblCard.crdType, dbo.tblCard.perID, 
    dbo.tblCard.crdACode, dbo.tblCard.crdNumber, 
                         dbo.ufnGetCardScope(dbo.tblCard.crdID) AS 
    crdScope, dbo.tblCard.crdColour, dbo.tblCard.logID, 
    dbo.tblCard.crdWorkStationID, dbo.tblCard.crdUserID, 
                         CASE WHEN dbo.tblCard.crdStatus = 12 THEN 
    '01-JAN-1800' ELSE dbo.tblCard.crdDateCreated END AS orderdate, 
    dbo.tblCard.crdDateCreated, dbo.tblCard.batID, 
    dbo.tblCard.crdMinor, dbo.tblCard.crdConditional, 
                         dbo.tblCard.crdCardEntireNumber, 
    dbo.tblCard.crdUseIF, dbo.tblImageExported.ID, 
    dbo.tblCardTransaction.trnDate, dbo.tblCard.jobReady
    FROM            dbo.tblCard LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.tblCardTransaction ON dbo.tblCard.crdID 
    = dbo.tblCardTransaction.crdID AND dbo.tblCardTransaction.ctyID = 
    4 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.tblImageExported ON 
    dbo.tblCard.crdCardEntireNumber = dbo.tblImageExported.CardNumber
    ORDER BY dbo.tblCard.perID, dbo.tblCard.crdID DESC
    GO
```

tblCard:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCard](
    [crdID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [crdStatus] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [crdDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [crdExpiry] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [crdType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [perID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [crdACode] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [crdNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [crdScope] [nchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [crdColour] [nchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [logID] [int] NULL,
    [crdWorkStationID] [nchar](25) NULL,
    [crdUserID] [nchar](100) NULL,
    [crdDateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [batID] [int] NULL,
    [crdMinor] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [crdConditional] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [crdEntireNumber]  AS (calculated field)
    [crdUseIF] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [crdIssuer] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [issBatID] [int] NULL,
    [crdVersion] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [NewFormat] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CASA] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [jobReady] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [CRN] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [BatchID] [int] NULL,
    [timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCard] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [crdID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdStatus]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [crdStatus]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdDate]  DEFAULT ('1/1/2000') FOR [crdDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdExpiry]  DEFAULT ('1/1/2000') FOR [crdExpiry]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdType]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [crdType]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdNumber]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [crdNumber]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdDateCreated]  DEFAULT ((sysdatetimeoffset() AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time')) FOR [crdDateCreated]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdMinor]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [crdMinor]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdConditional]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [crdConditional]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_crdUseICAO]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [crdUseICAO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_NewFormat]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [NewFormat]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_CASA]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [CASA]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblCard_jobReady]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [jobReady]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblCard_tblCard] FOREIGN KEY([crdID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[tblCard] ([crdID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblCard] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblCard_tblCard]
GO
```

tblCardTransaction:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCardTransaction](
    [trnID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [trnDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ctyID] [int] NULL,
    [trnDetails] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [crdID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [trnwkstationID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [trnUserID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblCardTransaction] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [trnID] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

tblImageExported:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblImageExported](
    [Number] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [perName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ImportFileName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [timestamp] [timestamp] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblImageExported] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Number] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Edit 2:
I've actually stripped this back to being a view with just tblCard and it still gets the same error

Comment: This is not a coding issue - there is no code to analyze, therefore question not appropriate for SO. Why do you need a multi-table query as RecordSource for a form? A form normally does data entry for only 1 table.

Comment: Please add the CREATE VIEW statement to your question. Maybe also the CREATE TABLE statements of the involved tables. -- This may call for "divide and conquer", start with a simple view of two tables, try if this works, keep adding tables until it doesn't. Then post the before and after situation.

Comment: It's multi-table because the user wants to see related information from other tables on the same form. Only one of the three tables gets updated. This has worked for years.

Comment: I've added view and table definitions. As mentioned this is over 10 years old and it's a bit of a mess

Answer (score 1):

I've finally worked this one out. Because Azure SQL is UTC date and time only, when inserting current dates, I changed all instances of GetDate() in insert and update stored procedures to *SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time'* so that all of the dates would be consistent. Other applications write to this database also and it honours their timezone, but because stored procedures are within SQL server itself it was writing as UTC.

For reasons that I'm still trying to understand, the view didn't like these dates. I changed the view to format them as dd/MM/yyyy and it started working again.